Blazor firing submit event even when the validations are not ready
I have a form defined as follows :
@page "/booking"
@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer
@using BlazorApp1.Models
@using BlazorApp1.Services
@inject IEntityService<Customer> CustomerService
@inject IEntityService<ReservableItem> ReservableItemService
@inject IEntityService<Reservation> ReservationService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<br />
<div class="form-group booking-form">
    <br />
    <h2><b>Hi!</b></h2>
    <p>
        Please enter your details along with estimated pickup and drop off time.
        <br />If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to reach out to us at
    </p>
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-group booking-form">
    <br />
    <EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnValidSubmit="OnSubmitForm">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
        <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
        <h2><b>Contact Info </b></h2>
        <div>
            <label label="form-label" for="name">Name:</label>
            <InputText class="form-control" id="Name" @bind-Value="bookingInfo.c.Name" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => bookingInfo.c.Name)"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label label="form-label" for="name">Email:</label>
            <InputText class="form-control" id="Email" @bind-Value="bookingInfo.c.Email" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => bookingInfo.c.Email)"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label label="form-label" for="name">Contact:</label>
            <InputText class="form-control" id="phone1" @bind-Value="bookingInfo.c.PhoneNumber1" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => bookingInfo.c.PhoneNumber1)"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
    <br />
</div>
<br />
<form class="booking-form" style="width:100%">
    <br />
    <h2><b>Pickup dates  </b></h2>    <div class="form-group" style="width:100%">
        <label for="pickup">Pickup (date & time)</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="pickup" @bind="bookingInfo.r.ReservationStartingOn" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dropOff">Drop off (date & time)</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="dropOff" @bind="bookingInfo.r.ReservationEndingOn" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <label>NOTE: Please provide time of pickup & drop off. Most of our bookings are single day. If you're interested in a multi-day booking, please call us at (
</form>
<br />
<form class="booking-form" style="width:100%">
    <h3> Select items for reservation </h3>
    <br />
    <table class="table" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in AvailableItems)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ItemName</td>
                    <td>@item.ItemDescription</td>
                    <td>
                    <select @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs args) => OnQuantityChanged(args, item.Id))"
                            style="width: 60px; padding: 5px; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #f9f9f9; cursor: pointer;">
                        @for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
                        {
                            <option value="@i">@i</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    @* <td><input type="number" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs args) => OnQuantityChanged(args, item.Id))" class="quantity-input" /></td> *@
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="submit-button" @onclick="OnSubmitForm">Submit</button>
</form>

@code {
    private EditContext? editContext;
    private List<ReservableItem> AvailableItems { get; set; } = new List<ReservableItem>();
    private BookingInfo bookingInfo { get; set; } = new BookingInfo();

    class BookingInfo
    {
        public Customer c = new Customer();
        public Reservation r = new Reservation();
    }
    public Booking()
    {
        bookingInfo = new BookingInfo();
        bookingInfo.r.ReservationStartingOn = DateTime.Now;
        bookingInfo.r.ReservationEndingOn = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        AvailableItems = ReservableItemService.GetAll();
        editContext = new(bookingInfo);
    }

    private void OnQuantityChanged(ChangeEventArgs args, int id)
    {
        var item = AvailableItems.FirstOrDefault(it => it.Id == id);
        var bookedReservedItem = bookingInfo.r.ReservedItems?.FirstOrDefault(rr => rr.ReservableItem != null && rr.ReservableItem.Id == item.Id);

        if (bookedReservedItem == null)
        {
            ReservedItem reservedItem = new ReservedItem
                {
                    ReservableItem = item,
                    Quantity = int.TryParse(args?.Value?.ToString(), out int result) ? result : 0
                };
            bookingInfo.r.ReservedItems.Add(reservedItem);
        }
        else
        {
            bookedReservedItem.Quantity = int.TryParse(args?.Value?.ToString(), out int result) ? result : 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnSubmitForm()
    {
        try
        {
            CustomerService.AddEntity(bookingInfo.c);
            bookingInfo.r.CustomerID = bookingInfo.c.Id;
            bookingInfo.r.ReservationCreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            CreateReservation(bookingInfo.r);

            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("bookingcompleted");
        }
        catch {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Error");
        }
    }

    private void CreateReservation(Reservation reservation)
    {
        using (var _ctx = ReservationService.GetDbContext())
        {
            foreach (var item in reservation.ReservedItems)
            {
                _ctx.Attach(item.ReservableItem);
            }
            _ctx.Add(reservation);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

The entity bookingInfo.c is defined as follows:
  public class Customer
  {
      [Required]
      [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long")]
      [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Name is too short")]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [Range(10,100, ErrorMessage = "Invalid age")]
      public int Age { get; set; }

      public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [Phone]
      public string PhoneNumber1 { get; set; }

      [Phone]
      public string PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [EmailAddress]
      public string Email { get; set; }

      public DateTime DateFirstContacted { get; set; }
  }

The issue is that OnSubmitForm fired when I hit submit, even though the values are null. The entities are annotated with Required and ranges, then how does it pass the validation ? Am I missing something here ?
EDIT: Updated and put the entire component code.

What is your RenderMode ?

@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer

How do you initialize the model? I start with a new default blazor 8 template and  initialize the model private EditContext editContext; private BookingInfo bookingInfo = new BookingInfo { c = new Customer() }; and it works as expected. You could provide more details for a minimal reproducible example.

Turns out that Blazor is not performing nested validations.
I had to include <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator></ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator> to address the problem.
With that I also had to annotate the EF entities with [ValidateComplexType] to ensure that extended validations are performed on this. This is still supposed to be in experimental stage, but it worked quite well for me. I'm surprised that no one else has hit this issue.
